# Bind in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

```
class Foo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
  handleClick() {
    console.log('Click happened');
  }
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click Me</button>;
  }
}
```

i tried to remove this code

```
this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
```

but there's no problem, still works.
Can you give me some examples that illustrate of what bind does in reactjs context (like in the first code), like if you remove this bind code, will results in error

Comment: Your handler never uses `this`, so it works whether you bind `this` or not. That's about it. If it used the specific instance, you would need to bind that.

Comment: can you give example that uses this that similar to my code? so i can know which work and which result will error

Comment: Just try with the `bind(this)` removed and something in your `handleClick()` body that tries to use `this`, and you'll see that it doesn't work without `this` being bound to the handler.

Comment: Create a state variable and try to log it as @underscore_d suggested. `console.log(this.state.foo)`

Answer (score 2):

[bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) is a JS function that sets `this` to the context provided.

You are actually not using `this` in your example, so it doesn't matter.

It's also worth noting that the arrow function `() => {}` is equivalent to calling `bind()`, so for example if you were to declare your click handler as:

```
handleClick = () => {
  console.log('Click happened');
}
```

It would set `this` to the value you expect.